# Add a column with the new value from a tuple value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this `df`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'loss': [0.044, 0.044, 0.038, 0.037, 0.036], 
  'code': ["('ac',)", "('ac', 'be')", "('ab', 'ac', 'be')",
              "('ab', 'ac', 'be', 'fi')", "('ab', 'ac', 'be', 'de', 'fi')"]}
)

df
     loss                            code
0   0.044                          ('ac',)
1   0.044                     ('ac', 'be')
2   0.038               ('ab', 'ac', 'be')
3   0.037         ('ab', 'ac', 'be', 'fi')
4   0.036   ('ab', 'ac', 'be', 'de', 'fi')
```

Now I want add a new column `added-code`, the new value introduce in the `code` column.

Expected results:

```py
     loss                            code   added-code
0   0.044                          ('ac',)     ac
1   0.044                     ('ac', 'be')     be
2   0.038               ('ab', 'ac', 'be')     ab
3   0.037         ('ab', 'ac', 'be', 'fi')     fi
4   0.036   ('ab', 'ac', 'be', 'de', 'fi')     de
```

Comment: Convert each each tuple to a `set`, and use `-` to get the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming there is one new value per row, you can convert to tuples, [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['added'] = (df['code']
 .apply(literal_eval)
 .explode()
 .drop_duplicates()
 )
```

Output:

```
    loss                            code added
0  0.044                         ('ac',)    ac
1  0.044                    ('ac', 'be')    be
2  0.038              ('ab', 'ac', 'be')    ab
3  0.037        ('ab', 'ac', 'be', 'fi')    fi
4  0.036  ('ab', 'ac', 'be', 'de', 'fi')    de
```

Alternative, as suggested in comment, to use `set` operations:

```
df['added'] = (df['code']
 .apply(lambda x: set(literal_eval(x)))
 .diff()
)
```

Output:

```
    loss                            code added
0  0.044                         ('ac',)   NaN
1  0.044                    ('ac', 'be')  {be}
2  0.038              ('ab', 'ac', 'be')  {ab}
3  0.037        ('ab', 'ac', 'be', 'fi')  {fi}
4  0.036  ('ab', 'ac', 'be', 'de', 'fi')  {de}
```

Comment: the fist suggestion is all I want. Thank you.